# When should we mark a Test case as "No Apply"?

Tags: manual-testing, test-design, testcase

When should we mark a test case as "No Apply". When requirement are not clear or when test case is not testable or it is not understood.

Kindly explain when to fail or pass a test case, rather than NA.